# Gas estimation failed in Remix

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, gas-estimate, inheritance

Can't really use the transfer function as it is written. It assumes the owner uses it. So made a new function for the "minting" function for the faucet to use. Not sure why the compiler message is so cryptic.

```solidity
totalSupply_ = totalSupply_.add(_amount);
balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_amount);
emit Mint(_to, _amount);
emit Transfer(address(0), _to, _amount);
```

Trying to create a Faucet for my ERC-20 Token, and getting a "Gas Estimation Failed" when running my `dripToken` function which looks like this (UPDATED):

```solidity
function dripToken() public {
  require(faucetStatus);
  if(!checkStatus(msg.sender)) revert();
  tokenInstance.updateSupply(oneToken);
  updateStatus(msg.sender, oneMinute);
  tokenInstance.transfer(msg.sender, oneToken);
}
```

I have narrowed it down to the line with the transfer call which causes the error. I now deploy my ERC-20 Token and pass that into the faucet contract on the following way:

```solidity
constructor(string _fname, address _tokenInstance) public {
  tokenInstance = MyToken(_tokenInstance);
  faucetName = _fname;
  faucetStatus = true;

  emit FaucetOn(faucetStatus);
}
```

My Token transfer function is from https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol
I just noticed I get a compiler warning on the transfer function which hints at the problem, but I don't understand why (yet).
Here is the warning:

> Gas requirement of function StandardToken.transfer(address,uint256) high: infinite. If the gas requirement of a function is higher than the block gas limit, it cannot be executed. Please avoid loops in your functions or actions that modify large areas of storage (this includes clearing or copying arrays in storage)

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {
  require(_value <= balances[msg.sender]);
  require(_to != address(0));

  balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
  balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
  emit Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
  return true;
}
```

I create my Token in the following way. I now initialize it with a small supply.

```
contract MyToken is StandardToken {
  string public name;                   
  uint8 public decimals;                
  string public symbol;  

  constructor() public {  
    StandardToken.balances[msg.sender] = 1000000000000000000;
    StandardToken.totalSupply_ = 1000000000000000000;                        
    name = "My Token";                             
    decimals = 18; 
    symbol = "MY";      
  }
}
```

Posted my code on google drive:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1EvKEVhD8bR2oKS2W1XNRQpTqVbieUcmC

Comment: It's hard to know without seeing the implementation of `transfer`, but I would guess  that it fails if the contract itself doesn't have a high enough balance. You might just want `totalSupply_ += oneToken; balanceOf[msg.sender] += oneToken; emit Transfer(0, msg.sender, oneToken);`.

Comment: I tried to swap the lines as you suggested. Still getting the same error. 
What does emit Transfer do?  Is that a different transfer function? I have removed my inheritance as well, and now passing in the token contract into the faucet. I updated the original post with more code.

Comment: `Transfer` is an event that should be emitted by your token any time a token is transferred. (By convention, an event  is emitted showing a transfer from address 0 when new tokens are minted.)

Comment: Noticed I get a warning regarding the transfer function, regarding high gas. Not sure what is causing it (yet). Pasted the warning in my op.

Comment: If you share enough code to reproduce  the issue, I'd be happy to try it out. It's a little tedious just making guesses.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. Added link to google drive. I noticed I was running remix with injected web3. I changed back to JVM and I don't get any gas error anymore, but the transfer function still fails. It complains that the constructor is not marked as payable. I thought the Payable keyword was only used when transferring ETH?
My original error might have to do with my gas limit settings. Still debugging.

Comment: The mention of making the constructor payable is a red herring. I think it's in that error message because it is/was a common cause of transactions reverting, but it's not related to your issue.

Answer (score 1):

See top of OP for answer. I think it was the require block that failed. Not sure why the compiler is so cryptic about it.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify the address that is calling transfer. For example, if the you are trying to transfer an ERC20 token, the code would be as follows:

`ERC20TokenAddress.transfer(msg.sender, oneToken);`

Without the leading address, the EVM doesn't know what is being transferred.

Comment: How do I get the address?  Currently I am defining the faucet contract in the following way: contract Faucet is ERC20Token. Would it be better then to deploy the ERC20Token contract and then pass the address in to the Faucet contract through the constructor and just remove the inheretance?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. The other option is to have a `setAddress()` function. It would look like ```function setAddress(address tokenAddress) onlyOwner { ERC20TokenAddress = tokenAddress; } ```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the same contract being the ERC20 token and having  the `dripToken()` function.

Comment: Noticed I get a warning regarding the transfer function, regarding high gas. Not sure what is causing it (yet). Pasted the warning in my op.